# Multiple USB cams on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, webcam, opencv

I am trying this for the first time, connecting multiple(four in number) cameras to ubuntu 14.04 but before buying them i though of asking if there are any issues in having all of them together? Would all of them get detected and appear under /dev/video*? I am using USB Hub to connect them to ubuntu machine.

Are there any issues with respect to transfer rates? i will be using OpenCV to collect video streams from them and capture would be 500 x 400. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATES:

I found some useful help on this [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781770/capturing-multiple-webcams-uvcvideo-with-opencv-on-linux).

Comment: i think (as they seem to be implying bandwidth will be the limitting factor shoud you have a LGA 2011 v.3 or other server-like motherboard, lates say for the sake of argument : the ASUS ROG RAMPAGE V EDITION 10 the you should be able to run a maximum of 18  cameras. if they are high resolution then a maximum of 8. (8 usb 3 ports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this experiment with five cameras of [make](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/ELP-2mp-ov2710-high-speed-120fps_60009468566.html), all having resolution set to 640x480@120fps and they all worked fine. In fact i have other USB devices connected too the ubuntu laptop. I controlled these cameras using OpenCV and v4l2.

One very important thing to mention is that, usually with USB2.0 controller OR hub-controller, bandwidth issues occurs when high bandwidth devices are connected often the ERROR message is "No space left on device". This cannot be solved even with USB3.0 Hub or controller if the device is USB2.0. Hence you need to connect USB3.0 expansion card to your computer which has multiple separate port controllers.